# Mysql delete a certain char

Tags: mysql

What is the easiest way to delete a certain character in mysql. I need to delete the * character from a lot of rows.

Exp: Alviso (San Jose*)

I tried to look this up in google, but I don't really know what I am looking for.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you cannot do this with a simple SQL request. You might have to use a real programming language and regular expressions.

Comment: @JulienBourdon Wrong. Read the answers.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa thanks for the answer, I wasn't sure so that's why I posted this as a comment, not as an answer. MySQL keeps on surprising every day :)

Comment: @JulienBourdon Don't worry. We (all) are here not just to answer but also to learn. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a simple SQL like this:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET fieldName = REPLACE(fieldName, '*', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) string function, and an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) statement.

```
UPDATE my_table t
SET t.some_column = REPLACE(t.some_column, '*', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
update your_table
set your_column = replace(your_column,'*','')
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

The syntax is:

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```